# Convert String to Panel

Tags: c#

The question is pretty self explanatory.

```
public void changeActiveField(int thisFieldNumber)
    {
        string thisField = "Large" + thisFieldNumber;
        Panel thisPanel = (Panel)thisField;
        thisPanel.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
    }
```

I know this doesn't work and will never work.
I would like the function to change the panel's BackColor.
every panel begins with "Large" followed by a number.

Sorry if this question is really easy, I'm pretty new at C#.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  All you want to do is change the back color?  It looks like you're already doing that.  What is your question?

Comment: Why would you be casting (if you could) a label to a panel, then placing it in a label? Your naming is very confusing, you say label, but you name it (and cast it) as a panel.

Comment: I just started with C# so no clue if I'm using WinForms or WPF.
sadly the below solution does not work.
I do want to change the background color, this doesn't work however :(
Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: I see I wrote Label in the title instead of Panel (still doesn't work though)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, your actual question is:

> How do I get a reference to a label with a name unknown at compile-time?

The solution depends on the UI library you use. In the case of WinForms, the answer is:

```
Label thisPanel = (Label)this.Controls[thisField];
```

If the panel is not directly below the form (but nested within some other control), use the [Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Label thisPanel = (Label)this.Controls.Find(thisField, true).SingleOrDefault();
```

Note that this expression will yield `null` if the control is not found. If you prefer a run-time error in that case, use `Single()` instead.

Comment: I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that this only looks at direct children of the form.  If you aren't certain what the parent will be, you will need a recursive search.  Otherwise, use `Label thisPanel = (Label)knownParentControl.Controls[thisField];`

Comment: @EricPhillips You are right, this would only work for descendants of Form.

Comment: @EricPhillips: You are right, I extended my answer with a reference to the `Find` method, which searches recursively.

Comment: I meant panel instead of Label, however the second line worked!
Thank you very much (sorry for messing up with the naming!)